# :Noob Alert: How can users in the same database add each other to their 'contact lists'?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, contacts

I am using Android Studio and I have set up a basic app where people can register an account, which then stores their information in database on a server. The user is obviously then able to log in.

I have been trying for a solid month -I wish I was exaggerating- to allow users who have registered to be able add each other to a contact list linked to their account within the app, but I have found nothing.

I am trying to allow users to search the database and for 'friends' and then add them to their contactlist.

Is it at all possible? I really have no idea how to approach this.

I have really google'd myself dead and this was my last resort.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you need to program that.

Comment: @zapl I have no idea how to approach it though, I have done the sign up and database but I don't know where to go from there. Have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By your explanation i assume that you already have a server and an Android client.

---

Does your database support such feature? If not i can give you simple a solution :

1. Give to each person an ID (should be your primary key) to avoid searching by name
2. Add a column to your user table in wich you will append a list of id's of their friends

By your explanation i can identify 2 different use cases:

1. Search people
2. Add a friend

---

For the first you should be able to retrieve a set of users and show them in the gui. You should add a method to your service API to retrieve users within an id range (or some other criteria).

For the second you should add a method to your API that allows a user to befriend other using his ID. The server should store it in the appropriate column within his entry in the database.

I guess you will have alot more questions... keep them coming =)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!

I am currently using a free server from www.000webhost.com, and I'm not too sure whether it supports the feature or not. 

I want users to be able to search the database for other users by either using their mobile number, username or email.

I have got a user_ID coloumn which is my primary but I do not completely understand what you mean by 'a list of id's of their friends'.

Like I said before, I do appologise for being such a noob, I just recently got back into java and it has changed quite a bit from when I was in school.

Comment: apoloigising for being a noob lol... i am a noob too :D. You have to understand that an apparently easy service provided by a  normal website can sometimes be very complex under the hood. You should be doing 2 separate projects, one for frontend and another for the rest services plus database. Since you are learning, i would recommend to start by the backend (services plus database): focus on delivering a service that the frontend can use.

Answer (score 0):

heres an overview of what you could do:

1. when a user enters a search term you need to query your database for results
2. once they select a 'friend' from the results, save that friend's ID to an array called 'contactlist' in the user's database entry.
3. to remove a friend all you have to do is remove that item from the array and save the new array to the database.

**Example Flow**
user searches '*bob*'.
check database for 'bob'.
show user results.
user decides to add bob to his friends.
add bob to '*contactlist*' array ["jim", "steve", "bob"]
update '*contactlist*' in the database.